Is there water coloring that will maintain color at 80°C?
I'm building a keg cleaner for my employer.  The cleaner has a caustic tank that uses PBW, and a sanitizer tank.  The current build is plagued with caustic contamination, so I would like to see visually when the sani tank becomes contaminated.
I tried using this brand of food coloring, but when heated to 80°C, the color disappears.
Is there water coloring that works at high temperatures?

The color should not be temperature sensitive since it is used for food coloring such as cakes (temp go up to 350-400 F). I think it react with your caustic contaminant. May be that is the indication.

Sodium fluorescein is quite stable, both to heat (it can be autoclaved to 300°C), and likely to the ingredients in PBW cleaners (though sodium carbonate peroxyhydrate might slowly bleach it). The United States FDA allows its use in food or drugs as uranine or D&C Yellow no. 8, so it can be considered safe for testing purposes in a keg cleaner. It's also comparatively inexpensive
A great advantage of sodium fluorescein is that it's highly fluorescent (hence the name), making it ideal for detecting even small leak or remnants of chemicals. Though clearly visible under ordinary room lighting, using an inexpensive ultraviolet flashlight, such as these from Amazon, makes it stand out incredibly clearly.
Hmm... reminds me of glow-in-the-dark beer.

BTW, you might add the fluorescein to the first rinse, rather than directly to the cleaner -- the little bit of peroxide remaining would have even less effect on the dye.

As it turns out, there wasn't any caustic contamination, this time.  The sani was reacting with corroded galvanized steel.  Thanks again for your help!
